# How to prevent a standalone kernel from opening windows?

Tags: linux, scripting

I am trying to make Mathematica do some plots for me as a part of a script. I have a `.m` file that basically does `Import[]` on some data followed by

```
Export["plot.png", Graphics[...]]
```

I run this with `math -script file.m`. However every time I am distracted by a window that appears for a split second when the above command is executed. Obviously this is a source of unnecessary focus loss and delay. I suspect this command is responsible as I did not see it happen when I commented it out. I also believe that a window is *not* necessary because I can perfectly well run the same script in a text-only runlevel and I get the output plot just fine. How do I reach the same behaviour when running from an X terminal?

Comment: If I press `Ctrl+C` during the procedure I get: `Interrupt during LinkConnect>` in the command line and in a few seconds a message box appears saying "One or more programs are currently using the Wolfram Language front end as a service..." This happens even if I unset `$DISPLAY` prior to running the command.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30866/2079

Answer (score 2):

You may use [WolframScript](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/) (its documentation page is [`wolframscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html)).

As it states in the documentation you can create a script file from *File | New | Script (.wls)*. It has a notebook similar to package development but includes a script header.  I put in two lines of code for data and export.  The resulting script file contained.

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
(* ::Package:: *)

data=RandomFunction[WienerProcess[.3,.5],{0,1,0.01}];


Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory,"scriptPlot.png"}],ListLinePlot[data,Filling->Axis],"PNG"];
```

I am on Windows and it seems that `wolframscript`'s installation directory was added to the system paths.  Therefore I just went to the directory where I saved the script with the command prompt and entered:

```
wolframscript -file Test.wls
```

I can also just type in the script file name since the file extension is registered.

```
Test.wls
```

No windows popped up and the follow image appeared in my documents directory.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think WolframScript appeared in version 10.4 or 11.  I believe it can be downloaded separately from the link I provided at the top if you have an earlier version.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your graphics export is requiring a front end.  This line below should cause it to run in background.

```
UsingFrontEnd[Export["plot.png", Graphics[...]]]
```

Alternatively try

```
math -noicon -script file.m
```

Comment: Thanks! That's my guess, too. But interestingly MMA can do without the front end as I can run this from a text console (unless it launches its own dummy X server just for that purpose in the background). Unfortunately `-noicon` does not seem to make much difference in my Gnome environment—not to the momentary focus loss, at least, but even the icon flashes quickly. I was aware of `UsingFrontEnd` but I think I'm looking for an exact opposite of that, if that makes any sense in the system.